# Locale.getDefault() shows error in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFo4X.png)``This is from the Google Android codelabs
When i try to build the getDafult error shows invalid reference

```
val divider = "  •  "
val tagDivider = "  "
val text = buildAnnotatedString {
    append(post.metadata.date)
    append(divider)
    append(stringResource(R.string.read_time, post.metadata.readTimeMinutes))
    append(divider)
    post.tags.forEachIndexed { index, tag ->
        if (index != 0) {
            append(tagDivider)
        }
        append(" ${tag.uppercase(Locale.getDefault())} ")
    }`
```

Comment: Hi, Can you share the snap of the error?

Comment: @mdb  the Local.getdefault() is underlined red described as an unresolved reference. I included a screenshot to my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the problem is you are importing wrong package !! So import the below package and use directly `getDefault()` method

```
 import java.util.Locale.getDefault
    
 append(" ${tag.uppercase(getDefault())} ")
```

Comment: Thanks wow i did not actually consider that